# Working with degrees minutes and seconds without conversion

Tags: units

Is there a way to work with angles in DMS without converting them to decimal degrees, that is to sum them, subtract them?

I do not know how to even enter it without using string. My idea is something like: `20°32'15.828'' - 22°32'12.8''`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use either [`MixedRadixQuantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixedRadixQuantity.html) or [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) with [`MixedMagnitude`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixedMagnitude.html) and [`MixedUnit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixedUnit.html).

In both cases the units you need are `{"AngularDegrees", "ArcMinutes", "ArcSeconds"}`.

```
p1 = MixedRadixQuantity[{20, 32, 15.828}, {"AngularDegrees", "ArcMinutes", "ArcSeconds"}];
p2 = MixedRadixQuantity[{22, 32, 12.8}, {"AngularDegrees", "ArcMinutes", "ArcSeconds"}];

p1 - p2
(* Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{-1, -59, -56.972}], 
     MixedUnit[{"AngularDegrees", "ArcMinutes", "ArcSeconds"}]] *)
```

From the output above you can see the longer form using `Quantity`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK, I guess +1 for technical correctness, but...OMG...it's worse than COBOL. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Of course a helper function can be used: `dms=MixedRadixQuantity[#, {"AngularDegrees", "ArcMinutes", "ArcSeconds"}]&`

Comment: I suppose it's clear that I'm complaining about *M*, not your answer.  I think carrying around these large, slow data structures internally is a waste. It's ok for UI purposes, although in this case, the formatted output is not highly readable.